# Por que esse exemplo de jquery da w3s não funciona dentro de web-inf?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom galera tenho um projeto em maven, e na minha pasta tenho essa estrutura

> src > main > webapp > WEB-INF > jsp > index> index.jsp, demo_test.txt

[Esse código está dentro do meu web-inf dentro do meu index.jsp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)
os dois arquivos estão dentro da pasta index.

quando eu  tiro de WEB-INF e coloco em webapp ele da certo.

Comment: O stackoverflow funciona melhor quando as perguntas são autocontidas, sem links para sites externos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. lembre-se também de dizer quais erros você obteve. "deu certo" e "não deu certo" não são termos precisos.

Answer (score 1):

provavelmente o problema é quanto ao endereço do arquivo demo_test.txt, como ele está dentro de uma pasta, tens que passar o endereço completo dele, algo como:

```
$("#div1").load("./jsp/index/demo_test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

A pasta `WEB-INF` é protegida por conter as configurações, classes e bibliotecas de uma aplicação Java. Não é permitido acessar qualquer recurso desse diretório via URL por questões de segurança.

Entretanto, é possível fazer  um *include* dentro do próprio servidor, isto é, um JSP acessado fora da pasta `WEB-INF` pode incluir um JSP dessa pasta.

Também é possível encaminhar (*forward*) um *response* para um JSP dentro dessa pasta a partir de um *servlet* ou *controller*.

E, finalmente, é possível ler arquivos dessa pasta usando o método `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`. Exemplo:

```java
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/jsp/index/index.jsp");
```

Mas geralmente isso é feito para arquivos de configuração ou outros arquivos estáticos e não para JSPs.